# Echo info from a database in foreach() only displaying information from first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains info on my users. I want to get the users that have activated their accounts and display their names and how many points they have.

So the database (`users`) has the following info in it:

```
first_name|last_name|points|active
Joe       | Normal  |199   |1
Jane      | Average |50    |1
```

All the code I'm using to print is as follows

```
$user_info = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `points` FROM `users` WHERE `active`=1");
$user = mysql_fetch_array($user_info);

foreach($user as $key=>$value){
    echo 'INDEX: ' . $key , '   VALUE: ' . $value;
    echo '<br> Test get First name: ' .$value['first_name'];
    echo '<br>-------------------------------<br><br>';
}
```

This displays the following content

```
INDEX: 0 VALUE: Joe
Test get First name: J
-------------------------------

INDEX: first_name VALUE: Joe
Test get First name: J
-------------------------------

INDEX: 1 VALUE: Normal
Test get First name: T
-------------------------------

INDEX: last_name VALUE: Normal
Test get First name: T
-------------------------------

INDEX: 2 VALUE: 199
Test get First name: 1
-------------------------------

INDEX: points VALUE: 199
Test get First name: 1
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Try `$value['first_name']['0']`

Comment: Same result I'm afraid

Comment: See the answer(s) below then. Forgot about the `while` loop. It's Friday, I'm in "weekend" mode ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row and returns an array in a specific format.

To fetch all users do a while loop:

```
$users = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_info)) {
    $users[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
foreach($users as $key => $user){
    echo 'INDEX: ' . $key , '   VALUE: ' . $value;
    echo '<br> Test get First name: ' .$user['first_name'];
    echo '<br>-------------------------------<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` only reads one row from the results. Your `foreach` is looping over the columns, not rows.

You need to call it in a loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_info)) {
    echo '<br> Test get First name: ' . $row['first_name'];
    echo '<br>-------------------------------<br><br>';
}
```